# Choropleth world map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, choropleth

I have read so many threads and articles and I keep getting errors. I am trying to make a choropleth? map of the world using data I have from the global terrorism database. I want to color countries on a factor of nkills or just the number of attacks in that country.. I don't care at this point. Because there are so many countries with data, it is unreasonable to make any plots to show this data.

Help is strongly appreciated and if I did not ask this correctly I sincerely apologize, I am learning the rules of this website as I go.

my code (so far..)

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
map("world")
world<- map_data("world")
gtd<- data.frame(gtd)
names(gtd)<- tolower(names(gtd))
gtd$country_txt<- tolower(rownames(gtd))
demo<- merge(world, gts, sort=FALSE, by="country_txt")
```

In the gtd data frame, the name for the countries column is "country_txt" so I thought I would use that but I get error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

If that were to work, I would plot as I have seen on a few websites.. 
I have honestly been working on this for so long and I have read so many codes/other similar questions/websites/r handbooks etc.. I will accept that I am incompetent when it comes to R gladly for some help.

Comment: Is it possible you supply the gtd data.frame, e.g. via Dropbox? Maybe you would get a more appropriate answer then.

Comment: I honestly don't know how. It is available online though, that is where I downloaded it from.

Comment: Well, that's a good thing to start with. Then maybe you could just copy the download link and post it in here ;-)

Comment: @flowla - The Global Terrorism Database is available [here](http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/contact/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on the nice work by @jlhoward. You could instead use `rworldmap` that already has a world map in R and has functions to aid joining data to the map. The default map is deliberately low resolution to create a 'cleaner' look. The map can be customised (see `rworldmap` documentation) but here is a start :

```
library(rworldmap)

#3 lines from @jlhoward 
gtd        <- read.csv("globalterrorismdb_1213dist.csv")
gtd.recent <- gtd[gtd$iyear>2009,]
gtd.recent <- aggregate(nkill~country_txt,gtd.recent,sum)

#join data to a map
gtdMap <- joinCountryData2Map( gtd.recent, 
                               nameJoinColumn="country_txt", 
                               joinCode="NAME" )

mapDevice('x11') #create a world shaped window

#plot the map
mapCountryData( gtdMap, 
                nameColumnToPlot='nkill', 
                catMethod='fixedWidth', 
                numCats=100 )
```

[image]

Following a comment from @hk47, you can also add the points to the map sized by the number of casualties.

```
deaths <- subset(x=gtd, nkill >0)

mapBubbles(deaths,
           nameX='longitude',
           nameY='latitude', 
           nameZSize='nkill', 
           nameZColour='black',
           fill=FALSE, 
           addLegend=FALSE, 
           add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! I am trying to add the longitude/latitude points to show where in the countries the attacks happened(i.e. concentrated in small areas). The problem is when I add deaths<- subset(x=gtd, nkill >0)points(deaths$longitude, deaths$latitude, col="blue", cex=.5) the points will go on the map, but I don't think the map itself is formatted with latitude/longitude because the points don't line up correctly, and if I were to adjust the window to make the map bigger the points do not stay in the right place like they would using the library(maps), map() with the points

Comment: @hk47 Thanks. Good idea with the points. When I did it they did line up correctly, however you're right when I rescaled the map window the points and the country boundaries moved differently. Off the top of my head I don't know why that is (anyone ?) and it's now late, i'll think tomorrow. You can also use mapBubbles to add bubbles sized by the data, I'll edit the answer to add that.

Answer (score 8):

Something like this? This is a solution using `rgdal` and `ggplot`. I long ago gave up on using base R for this type of thing.

[image]

```
library(rgdal)        # for readOGR(...)
library(RColorBrewer) # for brewer.pal(...)
library(ggplot2)
setwd(" < directory with all files >")

gtd        <- read.csv("globalterrorismdb_1213dist.csv")
gtd.recent <- gtd[gtd$iyear>2009,]
gtd.recent <- aggregate(nkill~country_txt,gtd.recent,sum)
world      <- readOGR(dsn=".",
                      layer="world_country_admin_boundary_shapefile_with_fips_codes")

countries <- world@data
countries <- cbind(id=rownames(countries),countries)
countries <- merge(countries,gtd.recent, 
                   by.x="CNTRY_NAME", by.y="country_txt", all.x=T)
map.df <- fortify(world)
map.df <- merge(map.df,countries, by="id")
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=nkill))+
  geom_path(colour="grey50")+
  scale_fill_gradientn(name="Deaths",
                       colours=rev(brewer.pal(9,"Spectral")),
                       na.value="white")+
  coord_fixed()+labs(x="",y="")
```

There are several versions of the Global Terrorism Database. I used the full dataset available [here](http://www.start.umd.edu/gtd/contact/), and then subsetted for year > 2009. So this map shows total deaths due to terrorism, by country, from 2010-01-01 to 2013-01-01 (the last data available from this source). The files are available as MS Excel download, which I converted to csv for import into R.

The [world map](http://geocommons.com/overlays/33578.zip) is available as a shapefile from the [GeoCommons website](http://geocommons.com/).

The tricky part of making choropleth maps is associating your data with the correct polygons (countries). This is generally a four step process:

1. Find a field in the shapefile attributes table that maps (no pun intended) to a corresponding field in your data. In this case, it appears that the field "CNTRY_NAME" in the shapefile maps to the field "country_txt" in gtd database.
2. Create an association between ploygon IDs (stored in the row names of the attribute table), and the CNTRY_NAME field.
3. Merge the result with your data using CNTRY_NAME and country_txt.
4. Merge the result of that with the data frame created using the `fortify(map)` - this associates ploygons with deaths (`nkill`).

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I have been trying to do for literally hours. I really really appreciate your work & patience.

Comment: I've added a bit of explanation. Pretty grim stuff.

Comment: BTW, the convention on SO is to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer. This way you may get other answers that you like better. Once you accept, most people will skip over it. (You can upvote, though...).

Comment: this is an error I am getting… gtd.recent <- aggregate(nkill~country_txt,gtd.recent,sum)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found

Comment: yeah I am just working on a project so it is time sensitive anyways.. but I will keep that in mind for my next questions.

Comment: Not sure exactly. It works on my system. The so-called formula interface for `aggregate(...)` is relatively new. Are you running the latest version of R (3.0.3)??

Comment: no I am on 3.02.. I will update and see if that does the trick.

Comment: 24 hours to accept? Not sure that is a correct description of typical time course. The OP can accept immediately and they change the acceptance later if needed.

Comment: Why so serious? anyways- when running the world<- read(OGR) I get a cannot open file error. Then again when I try to merge, I keep getting the Error message "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Comment: The shapefile link downloads a zip archive. This needs to be unzipped into a working directory. You point R to that directory with `setwd(...)`. Then the `readOGR(...)` command should work. Regarding the merge error, are we both using the same gtd database? Finally, you might consider trying @Andy's solution. It seems simpler.

Comment: As concerns the `aggregate` issue, check if `gtd.recent$nkill` is numeric. In my case, it has been of class `character` using `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`, and I had to execute `as.numeric` prior to the aggregation step.

Comment: @jlhoward, the link to the world map is broken now.  Any tips on finding an up to date equivalent?