# Worldmap polygon fill color based on category data

Tags: r, plot, gis, geospatial

I am trying to create a worldmap where countries get a different color based on the category they belong to.

```
library(cshapes)
library(foreign)
world <- cshp(date=as.Date("2012-06-30"))
progress <- read.csv("progress.csv")
```

The categories come from progress.csv, which you can find [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j10eu5usfmyccr/progress.csv).
Category 1 should be green, category 2 should be red, 3 should be blue and 4 should be grey.
Every polygon has an individual `cowcode`, which you can see by running `data <- world@data`. These cowcodes are also referenced in `progress`.
You also see that in `progress` are only countries with categories 1 to 3. Every country that is not in `progress` is category 4.

The question is: How do I use the data from `progress`to color the right polygons in the right color? What should I search for, how can I do this? (I also can only use plot()).

Any help is **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Why can you only use `plot(...)`??

Comment: No, it's not a homework assignment. I wanted to use ggplot, but my boss wants me to use plot(). That's why ;)

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625119/choropleth-world-map/22626144) might be helpful. To be honest, I can't be bothered to do this using `plot(...)`. If you want the ggplot solution let me know and I'll post it. Until then, your question is more likely to get attention if it hasn't already got an answer.

Comment: Well some solution is still better than no solution, so if you would be kind enough to post it, I would love that. Results are convincing in the end... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with `plot`: all that is needed is merge the category data with colors and merge COWDATA in world with cowdata in progress.

```
library(cshapes)
library(foreign)

world <- cshp(date=as.Date("2012-06-30"))
data <- world@data
progress <- read.csv("C:/joep/progress.csv")

# create data frame containing category and matching color
cat = 1:4
col = c(4, 2, 3, NA)
catcol = data.frame(cat, col)

# merge colors progress data by category
progress = merge(x=progress, y=catcol, by.x='category', by.y='cat', all.x=T)

# merge progress data with world data by COWCODE
p = merge(x=world@data, y= progress, by.x='COWCODE', by.y='cowcode', all.x=T)
p = p[, c(1,2,ncol(p))]
p[is.na(p$col),'col'] <- 'grey'

# plot map, make sure order is correct
plot(world[order(world@data$COWCODE),], col=as.character(p$col), border=F, ylim=c(-90, 90), xlim=c(-180,180), axes=T, las=1, cex.axis=0.6)


# add legend
legend('top', legend=paste('category', 1:4), fill=c('green', 'red','blue', 'grey'), ncol=2, cex=0.6, inset=c(0,-0.1), xpd=NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So here is a `ggplot` solution, as per OP's comment.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)  # for fortify(...) + plotting
library(cshapes)
library(foreign)
world <- cshp(date=as.Date("2012-06-30"))
url   <- "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2j10eu5usfmyccr/progress.csv?dl=1&token_hash=AAHgjBLIiez5OFszCL-Etaqn1ws_f8hkd4Ik3a6vrJ-bhQ"
progress <- read.csv(url)

mrg <- data.frame(id=rownames(world@data),cowcode=world@data$COWCODE)
mrg <- merge(mrg,progress[,c("cowcode","category")],by="cowcode", all.x=T)
mrg[is.na(mrg$category),]$category <- 4
map.df <- fortify(world)
map.df <- merge(map.df,mrg,by="id")
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group)) + 
  geom_path(colour="grey80")+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=factor(category)))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="category", values=c("green","red","blue","grey70"))+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_fixed()
```

The basic workflow is this:

1. Associate polygon id's with cowcode:              `mrg<-data.frame(...)`
2. Associate categories with id based on cowcode:  `mrg<-merge(...)`
3. Convert world to a format suitable for use with ggplot: `map.df<-fortify(...)`
4. Associate categories with map coords:                  `map.df<-merge(...)`
5. Build and render the map